# EF Core 5.0.9 corrupting unicode characters while UseCollation was defined

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, entity-framework-core

I see a weird behavior, not documented by anyone else on the internet.

I have a SQL Server 2019 (Azure) database with default settings. Some table need to be optimized for storage, so I choose `varchar(255)` with a collation of `Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8`.

**Behavior**

Say Russian characters like как дела become ??? ????.

I have checked this using default tools. The `varchar(255)` with the specified collation really can deal with these characters correctly.

But EF Core 5.0.9 cannot.

I have an entity (code left out for brevity)

```
builder.Entity<UsageStatistic>(p =>
{
    p.Property(prop => prop.Param)
     .IsUnicode(false)
     .UseCollation("Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8")
     .HasMaxLength(255);
}
```

This leads to the correct SQL table definition.

But when doing this (context left out for brevity)

```
_context.UsageStatistics.AddRange(usageStatistics);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The `??? ???` characters appear

Any idea how to deal with this?? Or is this a bug in EF Core?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the collation of the database, *not* the column? Are they different?

Comment: It still needs to handle Unicode characters, it's just storing them into a UTF-8 encoded column. Have you tried `.IsUnicode(true)` instead?

Comment: Also take a look at [Built-in Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#built-in-converters). You may need to add `.HasConversion<byte[]>()` which, for a `string` property is described as _The string as UTF8 bytes_

Comment: This is a bug and assigned to the Entity Framework Core team.
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/3407
@AlwaysLearning IsUnicode(true) though confusing, makes it nvarchar, which I don't want.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for suggestion to add a conversion, though, HasConversion<byte[]> is a bad idea. It would make EF responsible for encoding and decoding strings, this is SQL Server's responsability. 
Your trick would work for varbinary fields. If one needs to go thus far to trick SQL into working for me for strings, I don't need EF anymore.